# Angular Routing not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am trying to implement the routing feature of AngularJS but something seems to be wrong when I try to navigate to the pages as I feel my `routeProvider.when()` is not working correctly though `routeProvider.otherwise()` is working correctly.

Here is the link to the Plunkr

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/tu1C7k?p=info
```

Below is the code:

### Index.html file:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">

    <head>
      <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.6.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
      <script data-require="angular-route@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    </head>

    <body>
      <h1>Hello Plunker!{{5+5}}</h1>
      <a href="#Next">Next Page</a>
      <a href="#Prev">Previous Page</a>
      <div ng-view></div>
      <p>After NG View</p>
    </body>

    </html>
```

### NextPage.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">

    <head>
      <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.6.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
      <script data-require="angular-route@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <h1>This is the next Page</h1>

    </body>

    </html>
```

### Script.JS File

```
    // Code goes here
    var app=angular.module('myApp',["ngRoute"]);
    app.controller("loginController",function($scope){});
    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/Next',{
        templateUrl:'NextPage.html'
      }).when("/Prev",{
        templateUrl:"PrevPage.html"
      }).otherwise({redirectTo:"/Prev"})
        });
```

Any kind of help would be much appreciated.
PS: Code of `PreviousPage.html` is same as `NextPage.html`

Thanks

Comment: Your code look strange... are you using ng-view? Are you injecting just the view in one index... or are you creating one page ( html) for every routing?

Comment: One obvious mistake is that Prev and Next page should only contains relevant data. e.g. for Prev: <h1>This is the next Page</h1>

Comment: I know that extra html content is not required. But that shouldn't be issue here right? Issue seems to be resolved now though

Answer (score 0):

I have created a plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/oEDcMu4LnZUPOwXGPkbo?p=preview , I have enclosed you anchor tags in a `div` as of below.

```
<div>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!{{5+5}}</h1>
 <a href="#Next">Next Page</a>
 <a href="#Prev">Previous Page</a>
</div>
```

Also, `head` and `body` tags are not required in route templates. But that is not the culprit. But that is something which is not needed.

Comment: I don't think that extra html content was causing the issue. BTW, you just added those hyperlinks in a div right?

Comment: PS: Thanks for resolving it. :)

Comment: yes,I included the hyperlinks in a div.You extra html content was not creating the issue but that was not needed.

Comment: If you are satisfied with answer then please upvote.